# Is it possible to create a 'class constructor with a unicode caracter' in python?

Tags: python, class, init, built-in, python-unicode

By 'class constructor with a unicode caracter' I mean an analogous to the list constructor '[' or the tuple constructor '('. For exemple, can I define a class Circular_List, a '|' constructor such that when I do:
List = |1,2,3,4| it's the same as when you do List = Circular_List(1,2,3,4), just like
List = [1,2,3,4] it's the same as when you do List = list(1,2,3,4)

I know the '|' character means 'or' so it might not be possible to reutilize but maybe unicode characters that aren't used by python

Comment: In short: no. Not without substantial changes to the Python interpreter itself.

Comment: There's no way to introduce new syntax into Python.